# Applying graph cut algorithm to detect food in a plate

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm a student. my supervisor asked me for a project  to detect a food using graph cut algorithm.

I know that segmentation and labeling are the application of graph cut algorithm. 
But when i search the web, i find only the basic information about the algorithm. I need more details so that i can write the code from scratch. Can anyone help me with a good tutorial about that ?

Comment: For future refrence, I wouldn't really call this a programming question.

Comment: Are you limited to using graph-cut? I got pretty good results using Bag of Words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the original paper applying the graph cut methodology to image segmentation [here](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~yuri/Abstracts/pami01-abs.shtml). [Here](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~yuri/Abstracts/eccv06-tutorial.html) is a tutorial examining graph cuts and level-sets, two of the most prevalent segmentation methods currently existing. As a student, you should probably do a little more research into the problem and try some things out before asking SO to help you solve it.

Lastly, I am unsure why you tagged this post with OpenCV, but in case you were unaware: OpenCV has a graph cuts based image segmentation algorithm implemented called [GrabCut](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#grabcut).

EDIT: Also, [here](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/05/05/bust-out-your-own-graphcut-based-image-segmentation-with-opencv-w-code/) is a pretty good tutorial on making your own graph-cuts based image segmentation using OpenCV